# MYSQLI Select field from column and get other row from same table

Tags: php, mysql, select, mysqli

In my query I'm trying to get the `value` where `attribute_id` = '142' only if `attribute_id` 141 = 'K&N'

[image: table]

If attribute_id 141 = anything else such as `Flowmaster` then I don't want attribute_id 142 row

Not sure how I would write this query.

So far I am trying a join like below but it doesn't work.

```
$query = "
SELECT
part.value as part,
brand.value as brand

FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar part

LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar brand
ON part.value = 'K&N' AND part.attribute_id = '141'

WHERE part.attribute_id = '142'

LIMIT 0, 2";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die('invalid query');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $part = $row['part'];
}
```

**UPDATE**

I Think I got it now. I changed it to below

```
$query = "
SELECT
part.value as part,
brand.value as brand

FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar part

JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar brand
ON part.entity_id = brand.entity_id AND brand.attribute_id = '141' AND brand.value = 'K&N'

WHERE part.attribute_id = '142'

LIMIT 0, 2";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die('invalid query');
}

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $part = $row['part'];
}
```

Comment: I don't know if you were able to solve your problem or not, but you simply can use a `sub query` with `exist`

Comment: Yes however I'm not too familiar with sub querys. But it can also be done with a join as I show above in my UPDATE. Would it be best with a sub query?

Comment: I'm not sure about the performance or optimization, But I think in your case using a `sub query` would be a more rational way. It may depend on the number of records in your table

Comment: about 6000 records. Ok I'll see if I can get it to work with a sub query too.

Comment: OK, 6000 records is nothing to cause any issues. But if you want to optimize your query, please do some research on `exist`